# DataGrid - SQL insert query error c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to adding to table access and datagrid row with sql query. buy without a success. Any ideas ? Thank's
My sql query :

```
DataBaseIkuns.Instance.InsertToDB(string.Format(DictionaryUtilsDB.dictioneary[DictionaryUtilsDB.CommendTypes.AddObserver], o.ID_Observer, o.Lat, o.Long, o.azimuth));

  public static Dictionary<CommendTypes, string> dictioneary = new Dictionary<CommendTypes, string>
        {
            {CommendTypes.AddObserver,"Insert into ShowTableObserver(ID_Ob,Lat,Long,Azimuth)"
            +"values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')"},
            {CommendTypes.AzimuthLongLatFromOB,"SELECT ID_Observer,Longitude,Latitude,Azimuth FROM Observer Where  ID_Observer = {0}"}
        };



    public void InsertToDB(string sql) // It get the right values - 1,2,3,4
        {
            int insert = 0;
            try
            {
                if (con.State.ToString()== "Open")
                {
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    insert = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Here it jump's to the catch. why ?

                    if (insert > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Your Insert successed");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Your Insert failed");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Have a comment in the code where the program falls.
The value of sql when it falls :

```
Insert into ShowTableObserver(ID_Ob,Lat,Long,Azimuth)values('3','31.4','34','150')
```

Comment: Can you give us the value of `sql` when the exception is raised?

Comment: yes I edit the question take a look

Comment: It would be of the uttermost importance know to exact error message displayed in the catch block.

Comment: And did you use an Access database to store your data?

Comment: Yes, I use access as my database because that what I should do. And the error is Syntax error in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an Access Database behind the OleDb provider then you have a problem with the word LONG. It is a reserved keyword (and probably it is the same in many other database systems). In this case you need to encapsulate the field name in square brackets

```
 {CommendTypes.AddObserver,"Insert into ShowTableObserver(ID_Ob,Lat,[Long],Azimuth)"
```

Said that you need to start to use parameterized query. Your string.Format is another kind of string concatenation that leads to Sql Injection, parsing problems and subtle syntax error when you miss a single quote or other type specifier in your query string

For example

```
public static Dictionary<CommendTypes, string> dictioneary = new Dictionary<CommendTypes, string>
{
    {CommendTypes.AddObserver,"Insert into ShowTableObserver(ID_Ob,Lat,Long,Azimuth)"
                              +"values(?,?,?,?)"},
    {CommendTypes.AzimuthLongLatFromOB,"SELECT ID_Observer,Longitude,Latitude,Azimuth " 
                              +"FROM Observer Where  ID_Observer = ?"}
};


public void InsertToDB(string sql, List<OleDbParameter> parameters)
{
    int insert = 0;
    try
    {
        if (con.State.ToString()== "Open")
        {
            using(cmd = new OleDbCommand());
            {
                 cmd.Connection = con;
                 cmd.CommandText = sql;
                 cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                 insert = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
            ........
       }
    }
    ......
}
```

Now when you call the InsertDB you write

DataBaseIkuns.Instance.InsertToDB(string.Format(DictionaryUtilsDB.dictioneary[DictionaryUtilsDB.CommendTypes.AddObserver], , o.Lat, o.Long, o.azimuth));

```
List<OleDbParameter> parameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter()) 
{
      ParameterName = "@p1", OleDbType= OleDbType.VarWChar, Value = o.ID_Observer
}
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter()) 
{
      ParameterName = "@p2", OleDbType= OleDbType.VarWChar, Value = o.Lat
}
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter()) 
{
      ParameterName = "@p3", OleDbType= OleDbType.VarWChar, Value = o.Long
}
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter()) 
{
      ParameterName = "@p4", OleDbType= OleDbType.VarWChar, Value = o.Azimuth
}
DataBaseIkuns.Instance.InsertToDB(
    DictionaryUtilsDB.dictioneary[DictionaryUtilsDB.CommendTypes.AddObserver], parameters);
```